# If all things are equal (RAM, cores, database) is there any noticeable difference between SQL Server Web Edition and Standard Edition?

Tags: sql-server

I created a small project to learn web development using an SQL Server Web Edition 2019 database. It has 4 cores assigned to it and my web server has 64 gb RAM.

The project has grown a lot and now has over 10,000 users.

I want to improve the performance of the application I created which heavily uses the SQL Server database and I'm trying to get good value out of my next upgrade.

Is it worth upgrading to SQL Server Standard or am I best to max out the cores on Web Edition to 8 or 12? If all things are equal is there a noticeable difference in performance with low specs (4 cores, 64 gb RAM).

SQL Server Web edition maxes out at 64 GB RAM, so will updating the RAM to 128GB help in any way?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Have you checked whether the SQL server is actually getting maxed out on CPU? Have you checked the page life expectancy? Wait stats? Are you getting a lot of pageiolatch waits? Is there an opportunity to optimize the code? You could save a lot of money by spending some time determining where the performance bottlenecks are.

Comment: We have no idea on your kind of workload however *usually* the bigger bottlenecks are to be found with IO thruput and latency, CPU less-so unless you have a lot of cpu-intensive (obviously) queries or use compressed tables; adding RAM usually sees more benefit than cpu cores since more data can be cached requiring less physical IO. YMMV of course. More ram on a stand-alone SQL server beyond what SQL server can use probably won't help much, but on a shared box then more ram can free up resource for SQL Server - assuming SQL Server has its max-memory configured optimally.

Comment: If you can fit your whole database in 128gb but not in 64gb then yes it could make a difference. There are other differences also: TDE, backup compression and encryption, CDC

Comment: @Charlieface Until some horrible query comes along with a huge grant that wipes out a quarter of the buffer pool! OK, unlikely ;)